# App not compatible with buildpack Django heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Would anyone be able to give me a tip Heroku? Very new at this as well as Django.

I am trying to follow [these steps](https://dev.to/danimalphantom/deploying-a-django-blog-app-on-heroku-ja) on Dev using `django_heroku` that is imported on the `settings.py` file. Small snip of `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
Django==2.2.8
gunicorn
django-heroku
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-summernote==0.8.11.4
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

ProcFile:
`web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -`

Using the Heroku pipeline as mentioned in the blog post when I do a `git push heroku master`:

```
Enumerating objects: 237, done.
Counting objects: 100% (237/237), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (137/137), done.
Writing objects: 100% (237/237), 67.80 KiB | 6.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 237 (delta 100), reused 216 (delta 92), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to becomingme.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/becomingme.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/becomingme.git'
```

The build pack is something I am trying to research. It doesnt seem to matter if through the Heroku admin dashboard, setting the building pack as Python Ill still get the same error. Any tips greatly appreciated..

[image]

***UPDATE***, this is a screenshot of my project directory on my local Windows OS where the django app seems to work ok locally and I am trying to push to Heroku from this directory:
[image]

Comment: The "app not compatible" error happens when the key files (usually defining dependencies) aren't in the right directory. Make sure your `requirements.txt` is in the root directory of your project.

Comment: I am also using a virtual environment. I first enabled the virt env on my Windows OS, then git cloned a django repo, tested it locally, then after it seemed to work attempted the deploy to Heroku via the git Heroku pipeline. Does it make a difference that all my .py files for the project are inside a virtual environment? Sorry probably odd question

Comment: I added an `UPDATE` which is a snip of the current working directory that I am using to push to Heroku

Comment: Your requirements file is named incorrectly. It needs to be `requirements.txt`, with an "e" after the "r".

Comment: Note also that [you shouldn't be using SQLite on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+sqlite)

Comment: Cool thank you if you create an answer Ill hit the green check

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think we need an answer here. The linked duplicate has answers that cover this.